# not able to create pivot using macro if data is just fetched from db

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am creating a macro where i'm fetching some data from db and then creating pivot of that data . but while doing this i'm getting some 1004 error with some comments.
here is my code

```
     Sub CreatePivot()
     Dim objTable As PivotTable, objField As PivotField
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("data").Select
' data is name of the sheet 
     Range("A1").Select
    **Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard**
     Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("name")
        objField.Orientation = xlRowField
        Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("location")
        objField.Orientation = xlRawField
        Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("blaa")
        objField.Orientation = xlRowField
        ' Specify a data field with its summary
        ' function and format.
        Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("money")
        objField.Orientation = xlDataField
        objField.Function = xlSum
        objField.NumberFormat = " #,##0"

        ' Specify a page field.
        'Set objField = objTable.PivotFields("GENDER")
        'objField.Orientation = xlPageField

        ' Preview the new PivotTable report.
        ActiveSheet.PrintPreview

        ' Prompt the user whether to delete the PivotTable.
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        If MsgBox("Delete the PivotTable?", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
            ActiveSheet.Delete
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Sub
```

the error is saying 
I got this Run-time error '1004':- This command requires at least two rows of source data. You cannot use the command on a selection in only one row. Try the following: If you're using an advanced filter, select a range of cells that contains at least two rows of data. Then click the Advanced Filter command again. If you're creating a PivotTable report or PivotChart report, type a [it stops here]

here is my code getting stuck **Set objTable = Sheet1.PivotTableWizard**

when the same code i use by taking a fresh data then its working. here i fetch data from db using btn_click and two macros behind that.one macro gets data, then with 2nd macro on creat pivot is there. but the issue is coming.  Can anybody help in this?

Comment: thanks Mike. i tried the below approach. but not able to use pivot cache. Can you please help where to update my code. i read about pivotcache but don't get how to use here the same.

Answer (score 0):

Except omission, I don't see that you have declared `Sheet1 As Worksheet` .... by default it would be initialized as a `Variant` and hence would not deliver the proper object to the  `PivotTableWizard` method.

Furthermore the description of the `PivotTableWizard` (Excel 2010) says that

*This method isn’t available for OLE DB data sources. Use the Add method to add a PivotTable cache, and then create a PivotTable report based on the cache.*